# bazel run gives java.lang.NoSuchFieldError at CensusStatsModule

Tags: java, bazel, grpc-java

I am playing around with bazel and grpc using protobuf. I have created a simple greeter application following online guides and tutorials. I am able to run without issues using my IDE, using `mvn exec:java`. But when I try to run the binaries generated by bazel build command, I get the following during runtime

```
bazel-bin/greet_client
2019-02-05 22:27:49 INFO edu.jyo.app.gui.GreeterClient main Launching JavaFX client
2019-02-05 22:27:55 INFO edu.jyo.app.gui.GreeterClient$1 handle Sending message with text John
2019-02-05 22:27:55 INFO edu.jyo.app.client.GreeterServiceClient sayHello Invoking say hello
2019-02-05 22:27:55 WARNING io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor waitAndDrain Runnable threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: GRPC_CLIENT_SENT_MESSAGES_PER_METHOD
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$ClientTracer.outboundMessage(CensusStatsModule.java:311)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.outboundMessage(StatsTraceContext.java:172)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writePayload(MessageFramer.java:131)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.writeMessage(AbstractStream.java:53)
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingClientStream.writeMessage(ForwardingClientStream.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$6.run(DelayedStream.java:229)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream.drainPendingCalls(DelayedStream.java:143)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream.setStream(DelayedStream.java:112)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.createRealStream(DelayedClientTransport.java:365)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.access$300(DelayedClientTransport.java:348)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$5.run(DelayedClientTransport.java:307)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.waitAndDrain(ClientCalls.java:645)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:130)
    at edu.jyo.greet.service.protos.GreeterGrpc$GreeterBlockingStub.sayHello(GreeterGrpc.java:166)
    at edu.jyo.app.client.GreeterServiceClient.sayHello(GreeterServiceClient.java:37)
    at edu.jyo.app.gui.GreeterClient$1.handle(GreeterClient.java:38)
    at edu.jyo.app.gui.GreeterClient$1.handle(GreeterClient.java:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
```

The stacktrace seems to point to `opencensus` related jar.

The first thing I have checked is whether I have different versions of dependencies and I do not seem to have anything different between maven `pom.xml` and dependencies generated for `bazel`.

When I downgrade the version of `grpc` from 1.18.0 to 1.17.1 it works without issues.

My dependencies in bazel

```
#dependencies.yml
dependencies:
  io.grpc:
    grpc:
      modules: ["protobuf", "stub", "netty-shaded"]
      version: "1.18.0"
      lang: java
```

My `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <grpc.version>1.18.0</grpc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The complete source code along with generated dependencies is in my github repo - https://github.com/jyothri/grpc-chat

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Ashim Nope. Did not try again.